# zsh: command not found: nest

Tags: bash, nestjs

Can't run `nest new project` or `nest --version` on command line. I already installed it but these command line did not work.

```
zsh: command not found: nest
```

when i run `$PATH` in command line

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/makeba/.node/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.5/bin:/Users/makeba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/Users/makeba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin:/Users/makeba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/makeba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/Users/makeba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin:/Users/makeba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.5/bin:/Users/makeba/.rvm/bin:/Users/makeba/.rvm/bin:/Users/makeba/.rvm/bin
```

I really don't understand this issue.

Comment: zsh questions should be tagged zsh, not bash; they're two different shells, and not mutually compatible. That said, running `$PATH` tries to run your PATH as a command, so it's normal for it to say "no such file or directory". `echo "$PATH"` will print it, or in zsh, I'd suggest `printf '%s\n' "${path[@]}"` to print one line per element.

Comment: ...anyhow -- **where** did you install `nest`? What specific commands did you use to install `nest`? If the install location isn't in your `PATH`, there's the problem; you're giving us your PATH, but you aren't giving us enough information to know where the `nest` executable is at, so we have no way of knowing if that PATH is correct.